# Выводится undefined вместо результата выполнения функции dataTransportToString()

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Имеется следующий код:

```
export default {
    name: 'HowToGet',
    template: `
    <div class="dropdown-button dropdown">
       <button class="dropdown-button__button button dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropbutton1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-display="static">Москва</button>
       <div id="city-dropdown" class="dropdown-button__wrap dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropbutton1">
           <a v-for="city in cities" class="dropdown-button__item dropdown-item" :data-transport="dataTransportToString()" href="javascript:void(0)">{{ city.name }}</a>
       </div>
    </div>
    `,
    data() {
        return {
            cities: [
                {
                    name:'Москва',
                    dataTransport: {
                  "\u0411\u0435\u0441\u043f\u043b\u0430\u0442\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u0442\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0441\u0444\u0435\u0440": "139",
                        "\u041e\u0431\u0449\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0435\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u0442\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0441\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0442": "141"
                    },
                },
                {
                    name:'Калуга',
                    dataTransport: {
                    "\u0411\u0435\u0441\u043f\u043b\u0430\u0442\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u0442\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0441\u0444\u0435\u0440":"140"
                    }
                }
            ],
            transports: [
                {
                    name: 'Бесплатный трансфер',
                    dataMapId: "139"
                },
                {
                    name: 'Общественный транспорт',
                    dataMapId: "141"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        dataTransportToString() {
            return JSON.stringify(this.dataTransport)
        }
    },
};
```

Пытался привести данный объект к строке, но свойство data-transport и его значение не выводятся. Пробовал `console.log()` – в консоли выводится `undefined`. Где ошибка в указанном коде и как ее исправить?

Comment: эм... а где ты определяешь свойство `dataTransport` у `this`?

Comment: Ошибку понял, чуть позже напишу свой ответ

Comment: а ты точно уверен, что тебе именно строку надо передавать?

Comment: да, в итоге значение `data-transport` должно быть таким
`"{"\u0411\u0435\u0441\u043f\u043b\u0430\u0442\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u0442\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0441\u0444\u0435\u0440":"140"}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.cities[0].dataTransport`.
Это первое, что бросается в глаза. Там же массив, в котором содержатся уже объекты. Попробуй, а там дальше посмотрим. Вообще, я бы в функцию `dataTransportToString()` передавал бы индекс, если надо определенный элемент конвертировать, либо же в цикле весь массив обрабатывал.

Comment: он в цикле по cities проходит

Comment: @Grundy Да, точно. Увидел. Ну в этом случае в функцию нужно передать `city`, а с в теле функции никаких `this` в этом случае быть не может.